# Adaptive card Submit Actions are not working in MS Teams on iOS mobile app

Tags: c#, ios, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

We are working on a cross-platform bot. Adaptive card buttons doesn't seems to respond in MS Teams when used on iOS mobile. There is no response from bot at all. The card responds as expected when MS Teams is accessed via web browser or MS Teams application on desktop computer or via Android devices.

Here is the JSON, of which the text is replaced run-time.

```
{
   "type": "AdaptiveCard",
   "version": "1.0",
   "body": [
      {
         "type": "Container",
         "items": [
            {
               "type": "TextBlock",
               "text": "<heading>",
               "wrap": true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "type": "Container",
         "items": [
            {
               "type": "ColumnSet",
               "columns": [
                  {
                     "type": "Column",
                     "width": "stretch",
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "type": "TextBlock",
                           "text": "<Option1>",
                           "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                           "weight": "Light",
                           "separator": true,
                           "color": "Accent"
                        }
                     ],
                     "id": "1",
                     "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "actionButton",
                        "data": {
                           "msteams": {
                              "type": "imBack",
                              "value": "{3}"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                     "style": "emphasis"
                  },
                  {
                     "type": "Column",
                     "width": "stretch",
                     "separator": true,
                     "items": [
                        {
                           "type": "TextBlock",
                           "text": "<Option2>",
                           "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                           "weight": "Light",
                           "separator": true,
                           "color": "Accent"
                        }
                     ],
                     "id": "2",
                     "selectAction": {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "actionButton",
                        "data": {
                           "msteams": {
                              "type": "imBack",
                              "value": "{4}"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                     "style": "emphasis"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "$schema": "http:adaptivecards.ioschemasadaptive-card.json"
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, have you tested on Android?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Yes. it is tested on android.

Comment: I presume it worked there ok?

Comment: Could you please try to update your adaptive card schema version to 1.2? Please update he schema also to "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json". Let me know if this doesn't help you.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow .. your right... it worked well in Android.

Comment: ok great. Any update on this with iOS, following the schema correction, and changing to 1.2 as per @Trinetra-MSFT suggestion?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT .. There is a delay in verification as the device owner is away. I will respond as soon as I get the info.

Comment: @shehanaazsk Do we have an update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the actual cause, but your schema is wrong - it should be:

```
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
```